# How to partially collect records from RDD but still keep in order?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I recently need to collect a big data from a RDD in spark. The problem is the size of the data is too big so that I can't collect back all the data and store it in the driver's memory. So I tried multiple ways to implement this but still got failed.

First, I need to mark the records in the RDD with an index so I used zipWithIndex() function.

After that, I tried the 1st method: I used take() function to collect the first 10 million records from the RDD and then do the iteration on this 10 million records to do some processing. When it's done, I filter out the first 10 million records from the RDD and then take the first 10 million records from the new RDD (filtered one), and do iteration again. Do this loop until the RDD is empty. --> This doesn't work cause I need to count the initial RDD to get the total number of the records while this seems to consume a lot of memory. Anyway, it failed in the end.

Next I tried the 2nd method: I used the toLocalIterator to get the iterator of the RDD directly and do the iteration and processing on the driver. This seems to be a solution but it turns out that the performance is really bad. It costs too many time on the hasNext(). The testing is still on-going. Even it works, the performance can't reach the requirement.

So is there any other way to implement this kind of thing? Many thanks.

Comment: The questions is - WHY must you ship all your data to the driver? Using Spark, the best practice is to keep the data in the cluster, where it fits. Anything you want to do with it - do it there. You should only use methods like `collect` if it's for a small fraction of the data. If you have a specific requirement that forces you to perform something on driver side - write down what it is, there's usually a way to do it in a distributed manner.

Comment: The problem is that I need to build two lists as input of another single thread algorithm based on the distributed data. There is a dependency issue when building these two lists so that I can't do it in the cluster(I think but maybe im wrong). The dependency issue is the lists have to be in order and some of  the records have to be paired during the building procedure. (Pair means that two of the paired record could be stored in two different blocks)

Comment: If these two lists are too large for your driver memory - you're doomed anyway, right? If not - how come - can you work on each batch separately? If you can - do that on the cluster... If the lists _do_ fit in driver memory because they contain just a small part of each record - use `map` to transform each record in the RDD to just these values that you need, and then call `collect`

Comment: There a two components here. If you want to collect data you have to pay the cost. There is no workaround. Another one is the cost of running multiple jobs when you fetch data in batches. It can be partially avoided by making each batch as large as possible to fit on the driver by decreasing number of partitions. Still it looks  like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).